# How to fix 130 react error in react heroku?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, server-side-rendering

When i deploy my react to heroku, i have the following error:

```
p listening on port 3000!
{ Invariant Violation: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. 
    at ba (/Users/alexei.mairyn/opensense-admin/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:10:312)
    at r (/Users/alexei.mairyn/opensense-admin/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:11:166)
    at a.render (/Users/alexei.mairyn/opensense-admin/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44:191)
    at a.read (/Users/alexei.mairyn/opensense-admin/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:58)
    at renderToString (/Users/alexei.mairyn/opensense-admin/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:53:83)
    at /Users/alexei.mairyn/opensense-admin/build/server.js:1:23661 name: 'Invariant Violation', framesToPop: 1 }
```

Also, when i start command yarn start:production - i have the same error.

```
  <Switch>
        <DefaultLayout
          isAuth={isAuth}
          path="/meetings"
          component={ConferenceContainer}
        />
        <DefaultLayout
          isAuth={isAuth}
          path="/domains"
          exact
          component={Domains}
        />
        <AuthLayout
          path="/login"
          exact
          component={Login}
        />
        <ConferenceLayout
          isAuth={isAuth}
          path="/:id/menu"
          component={Menu}
        />

    </Switch>
```

Comment: It seems like you try to render an undefined component. E.g. by getting no data from the server or something like that

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=130&args%5B%5D=undefined&args%5B%5D=

Comment: @lumio i try to wrap my <Switch></Switch> in div and it can't help=(

Comment: Add your code that causes the trouble to your question

Comment: @lumio Done)
It's my App.js file